# Does the conservation of spatial components in the four momentum imply the conservation of the time component ( Energy)?

Tags: special-relativity, momentum

Does the conservation of spatial components in the four momentum imply the conservation of the time component ( Energy)?
If so how to prove it?

Does the conservation of

$$
\textbf{P}_3 = 
\begin{bmatrix}\frac{mv_x}{\sqrt{1-v^2}} \\
\frac{mv_y}{\sqrt{1-v^2}} \\
\frac{mv_z}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
implies the conservation of the time component
$$
\frac{m}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}
$$
and hence the conservation of
$$
\textbf{P}_4 = 
\begin{bmatrix}\frac{m}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}
 \\
\frac{mv_x}{\sqrt{1-v^2}} \\
\frac{mv_y}{\sqrt{1-v^2}} \\
\frac{mv_z}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

If yes, how to prove it ?

Comment: When you say “the conservation of spatial components” do you mean in some Lorentz frame or in all Lorentz frames?

Comment: In all Lorentz frames

Comment: Assume that the spatial components are conserved in some Lorentz frame. You can then transform to a different frame and see whether they are automatically conserved there as well, or whether something else is required.